# Read integers separated with whitespace into int[] array

Tags: java, arrays, int, inputstream

I read line with

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
reader.readLine();
```

Example input is

```
1 4 6 32 5
```

What is the fastest way to read the input and put it into an integer array `int[]` ?

I'm also looking for some one-line solution if possible.

Comment: Look up `String.split` and `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: I did it already but I'm looking for some shorter way.

Comment: Shorter ("faster") meaning fewer lines of code?

Comment: I am looking for the fastest way and also for the shortest one.

Comment: fastest how?  fastest to write?  fastest to run?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use `Scanner`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (scanner.hasNextInt())
  list.add(scanner.nextInt());
int[] arr = list.toArray(new int[0]);
```

Until we have closures in java, this is probably the shortest you can get.

`int[] arr = list.toArray(new int[0]);` won't work because there's no conversion from Integer to int. You can't use int as a type argument for generics.

But yeah If you are working with Java 8 then you can use Stream API for it with the below code snippet(Better way of doing things).

`int[] array = list.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();`

Answer (score 27):

***Short Answer***

**BufferedReader is Faster then Scanner**

Using `BufferedReader` and then splitting and parsing each Integer value is much Faster then using `nextInt()` method of `Scanner`.

---

***Explaination***

1. Use `readLine()` method of `BufferedReader` and scan the whole String.
2. Split this String for `str.split("\\s")`
3. Iterate over the above array and parse each integer value using `Integer.parseInt()`

The above method was tested to parse 1000 different integers and was proved to be twice as much faster then using `nextInt()` method of `Scanner` class.

*Code to test BufferedReader Class*

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class BufferedReaderTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int num[] = new int[1000];
        String[] strNums;
        long startTime, endTime;


        /*________ TEST STARTS ________*/
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        strNums = bi.readLine().split("\\s");
        for(int i=0; i<strNums.length; i++) {
            num[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNums[i]);
        }
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        /*________ TEST ENDS ________*/

        System.out.println("Total Time Taken: " + (endTime - startTime));
    }
}
```

*Code to test Scanner's nextInt()*

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

class ScannerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] nums = new int[1000];
        int i=0;
        long startTime, endTime;

        /*________ TEST STARTS ________*/
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        while(sc.hasNext())
            nums[i++] = sc.nextInt();
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        /*________ TEST ENDS ________*/

        System.out.println("Total Time Taken: " + (endTime - startTime));
        for(i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

*Input*

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382 383 384 385 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 393 394 395 396 397 398 399 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420 421 422 423 424 425 426 427 428 429 430 431 432 433 434 435 436 437 438 439 440 441 442 443 444 445 446 447 448 449 450 451 452 453 454 455 456 457 458 459 460 461 462 463 464 465 466 467 468 469 470 471 472 473 474 475 476 477 478 479 480 481 482 483 484 485 486 487 488 489 490 491 492 493 494 495 496 497 498 499 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 509 510 511 512 513 514 515 516 517 518 519 520 521 522 523 524 525 526 527 528 529 530 531 532 533 534 535 536 537 538 539 540 541 542 543 544 545 546 547 548 549 550 551 552 553 554 555 556 557 558 559 560 561 562 563 564 565 566 567 568 569 570 571 572 573 574 575 576 577 578 579 580 581 582 583 584 585 586 587 588 589 590 591 592 593 594 595 596 597 598 599 600 601 602 603 604 605 606 607 608 609 610 611 612 613 614 615 616 617 618 619 620 621 622 623 624 625 626 627 628 629 630 631 632 633 634 635 636 637 638 639 640 641 642 643 644 645 646 647 648 649 650 651 652 653 654 655 656 657 658 659 660 661 662 663 664 665 666 667 668 669 670 671 672 673 674 675 676 677 678 679 680 681 682 683 684 685 686 687 688 689 690 691 692 693 694 695 696 697 698 699 700 701 702 703 704 705 706 707 708 709 710 711 712 713 714 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 722 723 724 725 726 727 728 729 730 731 732 733 734 735 736 737 738 739 740 741 742 743 744 745 746 747 748 749 750 751 752 753 754 755 756 757 758 759 760 761 762 763 764 765 766 767 768 769 770 771 772 773 774 775 776 777 778 779 780 781 782 783 784 785 786 787 788 789 790 791 792 793 794 795 796 797 798 799 800 801 802 803 804 805 806 807 808 809 810 811 812 813 814 815 816 817 818 819 820 821 822 823 824 825 826 827 828 829 830 831 832 833 834 835 836 837 838 839 840 841 842 843 844 845 846 847 848 849 850 851 852 853 854 855 856 857 858 859 860 861 862 863 864 865 866 867 868 869 870 871 872 873 874 875 876 877 878 879 880 881 882 883 884 885 886 887 888 889 890 891 892 893 894 895 896 897 898 899 900 901 902 903 904 905 906 907 908 909 910 911 912 913 914 915 916 917 918 919 920 921 922 923 924 925 926 927 928 929 930 931 932 933 934 935 936 937 938 939 940 941 942 943 944 945 946 947 948 949 950 951 952 953 954 955 956 957 958 959 960 961 962 963 964 965 966 967 968 969 970 971 972 973 974 975 976 977 978 979 980 981 982 983 984 985 986 987 988 989 990 991 992 993 994 995 996 997 998 999 1000
```

Following were the findings when both of these codes were tested against 1000 different inputs

```
                    Scanner         BufferedReader  
                    (time ns)       (time ns)

Test Case 01        33855662        14202880    
Test Case 02        32779163        17772490    
Test Case 03        33421010        16625859    
Test Case 04        31901801        14552859    
Test Case 05        34890568        13943169    
Test Case 06        32913570        15342349    
Test Case 07        31733063        14153896    
Test Case 08        32063369        14368770    
Test Case 09        34354742        19922145    
Test Case 10        31760603        14441492    

Average             32967355.1      15532590.9
```

Answer (score 18):

Well, with Java 8 Streams this can actually be done in one line:

```
int[] array = Arrays.stream(reader.readLine().split("\\s")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

where `reader` is your `BufferedReader` object.

**Explanation**:

- `reader.readLine()` reads the input as `String`
- `reader.readLine().split("\\s")` splits that `String` on white-spaces returning a `String[]`
- `Arrays.stream(reader.readLine().split("\\s"))` creates a `Stream` from that `String[]`
- `Arrays.stream(reader.readLine().split("\\s")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)` applies `Integer::parseInt` to each element of that `Stream` and returns an `IntStream` consisting of the results of the applied function
- `Arrays.stream(reader.readLine().split("\\s")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()` returns the `int[]` containing the elements of that `IntStream`

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know the size of input, you can read input as string and then parse the string array to integer array

```
String[] arr=reader.readLine().split(" ");
int[] intarr=new int[arr.length];

for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 intarr[i]=Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Implement this class called FastReader as follows:

```
static class FastReader
{
    BufferedReader br;
    StringTokenizer st;

    public FastReader()
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

    String next()
    {
        while (st == null || !st.hasMoreElements())
        {
            try
            {
                st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            }
            catch (IOException  e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return st.nextToken();
    }

    int nextInt()
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }

    long nextLong()
    {
        return Long.parseLong(next());
    }

    double nextDouble()
    {
        return Double.parseDouble(next());
    }

    String nextLine()
    {
        String str = "";
        try
        {
            str = br.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Now Read integers separated with whitespace into int[] array as you normally would:

```
FastReader fr = new FastReader();
int size = fr.nextInt();
int arr[] = new int[size];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    arr[i] = fr.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 line = reader.readLine();
 String[] s = line.split(" ");
 ...
```

you can look to StringTokenizer also, but one of the fastest will be to read bytes and iterate them and convert the ascii (utf8?) coded numbers yourself ;)

Comment: I think an `int[]` was required.

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String [] s = reader.readLine().split(" ");
int []i= new  int[s.length];
for(int k =0;k<s.length;k++){
    i[k]= Integer.parseInt(s[k]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-compiled regex `Pattern` also to split String.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1)));
    }
    Integer[] output = numbers.toArray(new Integer[numbers.size()]);
```

Or you could also use pattern.split directly

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    String[] numberAsString = pattern.split(line);
    int[] numbers = new int[numberAsString.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberAsString.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = Integer.valueOf(numberAsString[i]).intValue();
    }
```

Gotta love regex :D

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer would be read integer inside the `for` loop using `nextInt()` method of scanner class.

Here is the implementation :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DriverMain {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the size of an array: ");
        int size = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter array elements separated by single space.");
        int[] numbers = new int[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            numbers[i] =  scanner.nextInt();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split method:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input[];
int arr[];
input = reader.readLine().split("\\s");
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(input[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n=sc.nextLine();
    String[] no=n.split(" ");
    int sum=0;
    for(String i:no){
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(i);}
    System.out.println(sum);
```

---

The Above code is how can you take space separate integer inputs using java programming and perform any task of your choice in my case I have added the numbers.