# Entering array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I found this code, which reads some numbers as arguments and then assigns them as values in an array. I can't understand how java knows what the array length should be ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = args.length;
    int[] dataset = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       dataset[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

    }
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(dataset));
}
```

Comment: Which array are you uncertain about?

Comment: what JDK are you using? Eclipse?

Comment: You tell it to use a size when you create it, in your case (`new int[n]`) the `dataset` array has `n` entries. And `n` is the length of the arguments array. Java will create one on startup with as many arguments as it finds blank separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to run this code through the command line. Example:

```
java ClassName 0 4 7 12 55
```

Java will know the length because it has an array of input values: `0 4 7 12 55`. This array is the same as `String[] args` passed into the `main` method.

If you want to learn more about command line arguments, then I'd recommend this [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

**Note**: there are some IDEs that handle command line arguments for you.

Answer (score 0):

In this code args is coming as command line argument and this define the length of array dataset. 
Command line argument are those which you pass when you run your code from command line.

Answer (score 0):

The array passed into main: String[] args comes from the command line.

So if you invoke your class, let's call in MyClass, using the command line:

```
java MyClass These are my args
```

args will be an array of ["These", "are", "my", "args"] so it will have a length of 4.

The size is determined by what you pass in from the command line.